# How can I capture the screen (with Robot) from an applet?

Tags: java, applet, screenshot

I know it is possible to 'capture the screen' with a Robot in a Java program.

But is it also possible to do this with a Java applet?

If so, what would I have to do here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible; signing alone won't give your Applet any permissions. You need to grant the createRobot permission to your Applet.

Check the [security tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/security/index.html)s for more details.

Comment: Ok on one tutorial now, it just says (As one of the steps) 'Sign the JAR file' How would I do that?